# Vite in React - Two output files share the same path but have different content

Tags: reactjs

`[ERROR] Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp_8576380d\react-CountUp.js`

```
Error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp_8576380d\react-CountUp.js
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\realestate website\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1649:15)
    at C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\realestate website\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1058:25
    at C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\realestate website\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1525:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

How can I resolve this?

Deleted `react-countup` from node modules. But it displays an error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.